Testing concurrency ability of a Django app
Let's suppose I have a Django app named MyApp in which I have a Django model called MyModel. This model has a method called process. The database is Postgresql so it allows concurrent queries.
What I need to do is to test if the MyModel.process() method can run simultaneously without problem.
So, in my tests, when I do
import threading    

class test_smtg(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.my_model = MyModel()
        self.my_model.save()

    def test_single_processing(self):
        self.my_model.process()
        # It processes successfully. 

    #However, when I do this instead:
    def test_concurrent_processing(self):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.my_model.process)
        thread.start()

It immediately reports me an error, such that the ID of my_model cannot be found in table myapp_mymodel. Why is that? Why is the program not able to see the object in the database while running on a separated thread? And what can I do to still test if the concurrency works whitout crashing my tests?
Here is more details for my MCVE:
import time

from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    def process(self):
        print("Sleeping for 15 seconds...")
        time.sleep(15)
        print("Wait is over!")

The database is postgresql.

Show us the actual error you're getting, with the associated traceback. There is no way I can see that Python would say "the ID of my_model cannot be found in the table myapp_mymodel" with the code you have.

In general, note that Django's tests use DB transactions to separate cases from one another, and threads would naturally get different DB connections, so unless you use TransactionTestCase (be sure to read the docs so you understand what's up), the other thread wouldn't see the other's in-progress transaction. But this is just an educated guess/shot in the dark since you're not showing us the actual error or the process() function.

Hi, thank you for your help. In my hurry to find a solution, I did not create a MCVE. I have been trying to make one today, but I cannot reproduce the problem. It is working perfectly. Here is the non-non-working repo if anyone is ever interested: https://github.com/vbrunelle/BugDemo1, This question will be updated with the MCVE.
I'd suggest to put this question on hold since the problem do not appears to be about the threading.
